# Local Outlier Factor only calculated for some points (scikitLearn)

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a large csv file, containing 2 columns representing the result of k-means clustering. I calculated 11 centroids, and the csv-file contains which one is the closest and which distance the point has towards this centroid.

The entries look like:

```
K11-closest,K11-distance
0,31544.821603570384
0,31494.23348984612
0,31766.471900874752
0,31710.896696452823
```

Then I want to calculate and plot the LOF using a script I found on scikit-learn.org

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
dataset = pd.read_csv('0.csv')

clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20)
# use fit_predict to compute the predicted labels of the training samples
# (when LOF is used for outlier detection, the estimator has no predict,
# decision_function and score_samples methods).
y_pred = clf.fit_predict(dataset)

X_scores = clf.negative_outlier_factor_

plt.title("Local Outlier Factor (LOF)")
plt.scatter(dataset.iloc[:, 0], dataset.iloc[:, 1], color='k', s=3., label='Data points')
# plot circles with radius proportional to the outlier scores
radius = (X_scores.max() - X_scores) / (X_scores.max() - X_scores.min())
plt.scatter(dataset.iloc[:, 0].values, dataset.iloc[:, 1].values, s=50 * radius, edgecolors='r',
            facecolors='none', label='Outlier scores')
plt.show()
```

But the plot shows:
[image]
With black points being the date points and red is a circle, showing how much it is an outlier

So I assume the LOF is not calculated for every point. But why? And how I calculate it for every point? And make it visible in the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normalising the data will help you in making more visible graphs and as per your code you have taken multipier of radius as 50 and I have taken 1000.

As we can see the algorithm does not mark red circle for every data point and it also depends on nearest neighbours(n_neighbors) we are taking into account fro algo to mark the circles.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, 31544.821603570384], [0,31494.23348984612], \
                             [0,31766.471900874752], [0,31710.896696452823]], \
                       columns=["K11-closest","K11-distance"])

dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

clf = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=3)

y_pred = clf.fit_predict(dataset)

X_scores = clf.negative_outlier_factor_

plt.title("Local Outlier Factor (LOF)")
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], color='k', s=3., label='Data points')
# plot circles with radius proportional to the outlier scores
radius = (X_scores.max() - X_scores) / (X_scores.max() - X_scores.min())
plt.scatter(dataset[:, 0], dataset[:, 1], s=1000 * radius, edgecolors='r',
            facecolors='none', label='Outlier scores')


legend = plt.legend(loc='upper left')
legend.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [10]
legend.legendHandles[1]._sizes = [20]
plt.show()
```

[image: result from the code]

Comment: Nope it didn't. It was helpful as it is realy more visible now, but still the most points seem to be not labeled

Comment: Can you update the new graph please it will help other to understand